# Mysql query to return data between two dates with a join

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

I am struggling with a mysql query to return data between two dates where a join subquery is involved.

Scenario: I have a product_revenues table and a product_costs table. I need to calculate profit by matching each revenue amount to a cost amount based on the latest cost start date for the last 12 months. So that is revenue in September and the latest cost from March should be matched in the data below. My data is as follows

### Product revenues table

Note: 'created' is a timestamp = 2023-09-13

| id | team_id | amount | stripe_product_id | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1000 | prod_1234 | 1694563200 |

### Product costs table

| id | team_id | amount | stripe_product_id | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 400 | prod_1234 | 2023-01-13 |
| 2 | 1 | 500 | prod_1234 | 2023-03-13 |

### My query

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(product_revenues.created)) AS revenueMonth,
    SUM(product_revenues.amount) AS totalRevenue,
    SUM(product_costs.amount) AS totalCost,
    SUM(product_revenues.amount - product_costs.amount) AS totalProfit
FROM
    sample.product_revenues
        JOIN
    sample.product_costs ON product_costs.start_date <= FROM_UNIXTIME(product_revenues.created)
        AND product_costs.start_date = (SELECT 
            Max(start_date)
        FROM
            product_costs
        WHERE
            start_date <= FROM_UNIXTIME(product_revenues.created))
WHERE
    product_revenues.team_id = 1
        AND product_costs.team_id = 1
        AND product_revenues.stripe_product_id = 'prod_1234'
        AND product_costs.stripe_product_id = 'prod_1234'
        AND FROM_UNIXTIME(product_revenues.created) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY revenueMonth
ORDER BY revenueMonth ASC
```

From this I expect a results table that shows:

| revenueMonth | totalRevenue | totalCost | totalProfit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 1000 | 500 | 500 |

The query returns results correctly when I change the costs start_date to 2023-**04**-13 and beyond but 2023-**03**-13 and earlier does not return any results.
It's as if 2023-03-13 and earlier is out of range but the between is 12 months.

Is it a mysql defect? Where is my query incorrect?

Here is the script to create a sample table and sample data to illustrate.

```
-- Create the "sample" schema if it doesn't exist 
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS sample;

-- Create the "teams" table
CREATE TABLE sample.teams (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    team_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

-- Create the "product_revenues" table
CREATE TABLE sample.product_revenues (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    team_id INT NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    stripe_product_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES sample.teams(id)
);

-- Create the "product_costs" table
CREATE TABLE sample.product_costs (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    team_id INT NOT NULL,
    amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    stripe_product_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES sample.teams(id)
);

-- Insert sample data into the "teams" table
INSERT INTO sample.teams (team_name) VALUES
    ('Team A');

-- Insert sample data into the "product_revenues" table
INSERT INTO sample.product_revenues (team_id, amount, stripe_product_id, created) VALUES
    (1, 1000.00, 'prod_1234', '1694563200');

-- Insert sample data into the "product_costs" table
INSERT INTO sample.product_costs (team_id, amount, stripe_product_id, start_date) VALUES
    (1, 400.00, 'prod_1234', '2023-01-13'),
    (1, 500.00, 'prod_1234', '2023-03-13');
```

Comment: team_id and stripe_id belongs in the ON clause., the rest of  your on clause should be in the where clause

Comment: can you provide table schemas and some inserts with sample data?

Comment: I think ON clause should contain names of columns on both tables whose values should match for joining. Like `ON product_revenues.product_id = product_costs.product_id`.

Comment: I have have added a sample script to create schema and small sample to show the issue. The query returns data correctly when you cost start_date is April but when date is March or earlier it does not. I'm stumped.

Comment: I also have tried joining  `ON product_revenues.product_id = product_costs.product_id`

Comment: Did you notice that: `SELECT Max(start_date) FROM product_costs` returns `2023-03-13`, and that this value (according to your query) **must** be equal to `product_costs.start_date` ?  So, what is your expected result based on this sample data?  Does this look ok?: https://dbfiddle.uk/i877V6Qs (notice the commented lines from 10-15)

Comment: I need the `Select Max(start_date)` expression because I need to pull the latest cost. 
Commenting out the 10-15lines looks like it causes revenue to be double counted and costs to be added up.

In this scenario results should be 1000 minus 500 because 500 is the latest cost record...

Comment: I added two more queries in live example, are they helpful? https://dbfiddle.uk/HLmuekdE

Comment: And another variant, the [lateral derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html) - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lcT94jMC). Why are you mixing dates and Unix timestamps?

Comment: Using the lateral derived table has worked. `with res as` . Thank you both. @FriendlyDragon